# Websphere 8.5: Application is not installed inside "installedApps" directory

Tags: java, server, websphere-8

I am new to WebSphere. Had installed the Websphere 8.5 server with single profile. And also installed JDK7 and enabled(Because, Websphere 8.5 comes with JDK6 by default). Finally, installed the application. But installed application is not getting updated in '**installedApps**' directory.

By default, the application should be installed in below path.(I didnt override)
*C:\WebSphere85\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\VW7MSPTCSPQADKNode01Cel*

But, application installed in
*C:\WebSphere85\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01*

Dont know where it overrided this path. Please help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible to override default path during the installation - check [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rapp_installoptions.html) - so maybe someone changed that during installation of that particular app.

Answer (score 1):

That location is defined by a server variable called APP_INSTALL_ROOT.  It should be defined in a variables.xml file in either the cell or node scope - for example, in profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/VW7MSPTCSPQADKNode01Cel/nodes/VW7MSPTCSPQADKNode01.  You should be able to edit that variable definition through the administrative console.

The location you said you actually wanted is the default, so it apparently was overridden at some point; it's hard to know how that might have happened after the fact, though.

Comment: I checked with websphere environment variable in admin console. It is also fine. "APP_INSTALL_ROOT = ${USER_INSTALL_ROOT}/installedApps", "USER_INSTALL_ROOT = C:/WebSphere85/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01".

Comment: But, the installed application doesn't place in "installedApps" directory.

Answer (score 0):

If .ear or .war file was installed manually via WAS Admin's Console after all installation steps, user will be presented with screen to confirm successful installation. There are few active buttons at the bottom something like "Save", "Cancel" and "Manage Applications". If user clicks "Manage Applications" he will be redirected to page where app can be started/paused/deleted and app files will be stored under

```
C:\IBM\WAS\Profiles\customWas85\wstemp\0\workspace\cells\USERNAMENode01Cell\applications\app.ear\app.ear
```

If user selects "Save" in above mentioned page, installed app files will be transferred to

```
C:\IBM\WAS\Profiles\customWas85\installedApps\USERNAMENode01Cell\app.ear
```

I would assume first approach uses some temp workspace folder "wstemp", second approach uses directory defined in "WebSphere Variables" as APP_INSTALL_ROOT.

This is [confirmation](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/know-flow-when-deploying-your-enterprise-application-websphere-application-server) for my observations

> 3. Uploading your application
>      The install process begins by first uploading your application file (EAR) to a temp directory.  If you are using the administrative console to install your application, wstemp is used as the temporary working directory.  For example:
>      profile_root/wstemp/0/upload/app_name.ear
> 4. Processing installation options
>      After your application file has been uploaded, the installation options are read in, processed, and written to your installedApps directory:
>      profile_root/installedApps
> 5. Saving deployment metadata
>      At this point, the install process stores the EAR file in the following directory:
>      profile_root/config/cells/cell_name/applications/app_name.ear/